When is a quotient of a $C^*$-algebra unital?
Let $A$ be a nonunital $C^*$-algebra. Is there a useful characterization of which (closed 2-sided) ideals $I$ of $A$ are such that $A/I$ is unital?
In the commutative case, this happens if and only if $I = C_0(\widehat{A} \setminus K)$ for some compact subset $K \subseteq \widehat{A}$. So in a sense, it should be a noncommutative notion of cocompactness.

I don’t know if you’d count this as “useful”, but this happens iff $e_i + I$ converges in norm in $A/I$ for any (or equivalently all) approximate identity $(e_i)$ of $A$.
